# Creating application with permissions using webservice API

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to create a serviceProvider including permissions using the webservice API of WSO2IS 5.1.0

The API I'm using is the one you can find on https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Identity+Application+Management+API

Simply creating a serviceProvider with the request below works fine.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <xsd:createApplication>
     <xsd:serviceProvider>
        <xsd1:applicationName>APP_NAME</xsd1:applicationName>
        <xsd1:description>My application name</xsd1:description>
     </xsd:serviceProvider>
  </xsd:createApplication>
```

Trying to create a serviceProvider with permissions with the request below fails with the message

> Error while storing permissions for application APP_NAME

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <xsd:createApplication>
     <xsd:serviceProvider>
        <xsd1:applicationName>APP_NAME</xsd1:applicationName>
        <xsd1:description>My application name</xsd1:description>
        <xsd1:permissionAndRoleConfig>
           <xsd1:permissions>
              <xsd1:value>permission1</xsd1:value>
           </xsd1:permissions>
        </xsd1:permissionAndRoleConfig>
     </xsd:serviceProvider>
  </xsd:createApplication>
```

I cannot find any further information in the logs and also the example request messages on the WSO2 documentation site are lacking any information.

Any help or suggestion is welcome

Comment: Try first creating the service provider using createApplication only with name and the description and then update the required details using updateApplication.

Comment: Already tried that one as well and it was not working. But I will give it an extra try and report my findings

Comment: Tried updating the application, but it is totally unclear what data to sent. Should I completely include the current situation which is created after I created an application?